# How to put more weight on certain features in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

If using a library like scikit-learn, how do I assign more weight on certain features in the input to a classifier like SVM? Is this something people do or not?

Comment: Why would you do this? Good algorithms already do this automatically and situationnally.

Comment: Look at TF-IDF - it does weighting

Comment: @Paparazzi tfidf is not about weighting features, it is more about "squashing" too rapidly growing ones so you get reasonable scales. It does not lead to a certain feature being "more important" unless you use very specific classifier on top (for example for decision trees, tfidf is not about "importance" at all)

Comment: @lejlot What ever.  If number of occurrences and inverse document frequency is not a weight then what it is?

Comment: It is "just" a representation, not a weight in the sense OP is asking for. Classifier is not "forced" to focus on particular feature due to number of occurences (value of tfidf). It will work as a weight for some models though, as described in the answer - it requires classifier to prefer high values of features, which is not a general property of ML models.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all - **you should probably not do it**. The whole concept of machine learning is to use statistical analysis **to assign optimal weights**. You are interfering here with the whole concept, thus you need **really strong evidence that this is crucial** to the process you are trying to model, and for some reason your model is currently missing it.

That being said - there is no general answer. This is purely model specific, some of which will allow you to weight features - in random forest you could bias distribution from which you sample features to analyse towards the ones that you are interested in; in SVM it should be enough to just multiply given feature by a constant - remember when you were told to normalize your features in SVM? This is why - you can use the scale of features to 'steer' your classifier towards given features. The ones with high values will be preffered. This will actually work for most linear weight norm-regularized models (regularized logistic regression, ridge regression, lasso etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I noticed in scikit-learn, the SVC classifier has a 'sample_weight' input where you can give more importance to certain classes. Can you give an example where this feature is used?

Comment: sample_weight is to weight specific **samples** (instances, points, objects), not whole classes (although it can be used for this purpose). This is used for example to implement boosting methods, which iteratively overweight samples which are incorrectly classified previously. It is also used to overweight minority classes in unbalanced classification. However, again this is a different kind of weighting than the one in the question

Comment: @lejlot Should I multiply the feature by the constant during training, inference or both? And should this multiplication be before standardization or after? Thanks!

Comment: multiplication only works for *some* models. In this case it would be during both training and inference, and after standarization.

Comment: Thanks @lejlot, I believe this would work for SVMs, L1/L2 logistic regression and any weight-regularized linear model, apart from the models you stated in your answer?

Comment: @lejlot also, if you scale it after standardization, won't it have no effect on the weights of a linear model? For example, if you multiply normalized feature f1 by a factor 'k,' won't the model just learn w1/k instead of w1?

Comment: Again - it only works for *some* models, the ones that are not affine transformations invariant. However, if you had to normalize your data, then your model clearly is not affine transformations invariant (otherwise it could just learn the normalisation on its own). In particular SVMs are not invariant to rescalings. Neither is (regularised!) logistic regression and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is:
Assume you have f[1,2,..N] and weight of particular feature is w_f[0.12,0.14...N].
First of all, you need to normalize features by any feature scaling methods and then you need to also normalize the weights of features w_f to [0-1] range and then multiply the normalized weight by f[1,2,..N] with the new transformed features.
Remember you need to transform this in test data as well.

Now you can check the performance of both models: without introducing the feature and with introducing the feature.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, I **wouldn't suggest** using index weights as that is the job of ML. However, a ranking of weights in my opinion will have to be done in the original data source (database table, .txt, etc.) by updating an additional field and always with the range from 0 to 1 i.e., 0.1, 0.2. ... 0.7 ...), and certainly always in absolute correlation with the corresponding features(parameters).