# Considering one column more important than others

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, xgboost

In case of 3 columns data, (In my test case) I can see that all the columns are valued as equal.

```
random_forest.feature_importances_

array([0.3131602 , 0.31915436, 0.36768544])
```

Is there any way to add waitage to one of the columns?

---

Update:

I guess xgboost can be used in this case.
I tried, but getting this error:

```
import xgboost as xgb

param = {}
num_round = 2

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, y)
dtest  = xgb.DMatrix(x_test_split)

dtrain_split = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest_split = xgb.DMatrix(X_test)

gbdt = xgb.train(param, dtrain_split, num_round)
y_predicted = gbdt.predict(dtest_split)

rmse_pred_vs_actual = xgb.rmse(y_predicted, y_test)
```

AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'rmse'

Comment: In short, don't do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is by assuming xgb has method "rmse":

`rmse_pred_vs_actual = xgb.rmse(y_predicted, y_test)`

It is literally written: `AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'rmse'`

Use `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error`

By:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# Your code
rmse_pred_vs_actual = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predicted)
```

It'll fix your error but it still doesn't control a feature importance.

Now, if you really want to change the importance of a feature, you need to be creative about how to make a change like this. There is no text book solution that I know of and no method in xgboost that I know of. You can follow the link Stev posted in a comment to your question and maybe get some ideas (including changing your ML algorithm).