# How to put more weight on certain instances in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I found a related question here: [How to put more weight on certain features in machine learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning) but is is for features.

Say I have a dataset of `N` instances (or `N` rows) with labels.

I know that some labels are ground truth, while some other labels are not certain, i.e. there is noise in some labels.

How could I incorporate this information into a machine learning model, say `xgboost`, for instance to tell `xgboost` that put more weight on the instances with verified labels than the instances with un-verified labels?

Comment: `xgboost` has an argument `case.weights` exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `DMatrix` and use its `weight` attribute to initialise weight for each instance. Check the docs [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)

or `sample_weight` from [fit](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit) method