# How do I assign higher weights to a customer's more recent encounters for classification model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

I am using python to construct a classification model using 5 years of customer data. I used a RFC and used a sample_weight. I was wondering if there is a model where I can manually assign weights to more recent encounters, so past 1 year has a greater weight than an encounter 5 years ago.

Comment: I think there are two interesting sources for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning#:~:text=The%20whole%20concept%20of%20machine%20learning%20is%20to,being%20said%20-%20there%20is%20no%20general%20answer.                                                                  and: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/machine-learning-what-why-how-weighting.html

Comment: You have tagged `random-forest` - is your question in according to that or just *any* algorithm where it's doable?