# Weight input features according to feature importance ranking of random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

My dependent variable is **land surface temperature (LST)**, and the independent variables are **elevation**, **latitude**, **solar radiation**, and **vegetation index**, with a total of **four types of features**.  The **rf_fit** regression model was constructed using the **Ranger** package in R to regress predictions of surface temperature.

I got the **importance** of four types of features through `varImp(rf_fit)`. The order from high to low is solar radiation, elevation, latitude, and vegetation index.

How can I **assign more weights** to certain features in the input?  The weights are assigned based on the order of importance. For example, the solar radiation is the most important, and the solar radiation is given a higher weight, the vegetation index is the least important, and the vegetation index is given the smallest weight.

````
set.seed(123) 
#Build a random forest regression model
#LST is the dependent variable, train is the four types of input features
system.time(rf_fit <- train(LST ~.,data = train,method = 'ranger',importance = 'impurity', trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv',number = 10))  ) 

#Model summary
rf_fit 

#order of importance
varImp(rf_fit)

#Model prediction
test_ ranger_RMSE <- sqrt(mean((test $LST-predict(rf_fit,test))^2)) ```
````

Comment: I don't think you should be doing that. Why would you tell a model which features are more important than others? That's what you want the model to tell you, right?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I really need the model to tell me which features are more important. I want to divide the most important feature (elevation) and divide the Land surface temperature(LST) into four intervals (P1, P2, P3, P4) according to the elevation, and build a model for each interval,  Set different weights for each model, and then combine these four models, `rf_fit = 0.1P1 + 0.2P2 +0.3P3 +0.4P4`, is this reasonable?

Comment: The way I see it, not really. Why should a model obtained for higher elevation (P4) be more important than a P1 model? Where would the weights (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4) come from?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion. First, elevation is the most important feature given by the random forest model, I divided the (Land surface temperature)LST into 4 LST intervals with different elevations. (My study area varies greatly in elevation). Secondly, the four parameters of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and 0.4 are the weights I assumed. I don't know how to get the weights of the LST model at different elevations. Is this idea feasible?

Comment: I really don't know about this, seems a bit overcomplicated/weird to me. And it is also getting quite off topic here on SO, this is more of a statistical question.

Comment: This is not a good idea, and it goes against all known best practices: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270640/scikit-learn-adding-weights-to-features , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning . The role of feature importance is not this, and if there is not a relevant setting on an algo for this, it is a safe bet that it is not meant to be done.

Comment: Thank you for the link you shared. I have read the two links. At present, it is impossible to calculate the weight of the feature, right?